# Not able to display all rows dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have 7 team member and im just able to display 1 of them in id demo, how can i display all my team members? PFB HTML code and javascript one what im using for the same:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 mb-0" style="display: flex;align-items: center;">
                <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><h6>My team</h6>
                    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">My team members:<br><h7 id="demo"></h7><br></span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <ol class="breadcrumb"></ol>

        <script>
            // When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
            function myFunction() {
            var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
            popup.classList.toggle("show");
            var data1 = "TEAMSEARCH";
            //alert(data1);             
            $.ajax({
                url : 'TeamAssignment',
                type : 'POST',
                data : {
                    data1 : data1
                },
                success : function(result) {
                     var memberList = $.parseJSON(result);
                     //alert ( "Returned rows " + memberList.length);
                     for (var i = 0; i < memberList.length; i++)
                        {
                           console.log(memberList[i].fullName );
                           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = memberList[i].fullName;
                       }
                }
            });
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = memberList[i].fullName`

Each iteration of the loop rewrites the entire innerHTML of `demo`. You probably want something like `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<li>' + memberList[i].fullName + '</li>'`

the `+=` is the actually important part.

Comment: yes, thats what i need... Now is working thanks buddy.

Comment: sure, just need 6 mins to do it, page dont let me do it till 6 more mins you are too fast hehe

Answer (score 1):

You repeatedly overwrite the `demo` `innerHTML`. You should make the assignment right after the `for` loop.

try something like this:

```
var members = '';
for (var i = 0; i < memberList.length; i++) {
    console.log(memberList[i].fullName );
    members += memberList[i].fullName;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = members;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below one:

`var memberList = $.parseJSON(result);
$("#demo").html('') // here just make empty innetHTML
for(var member of memberList)
   $("#demo").append('<li>' + member.fullName + '</li>') // here appending html string of each member`